# How to add everwebinar form directly to page instead of opening it in POP UP?

Tags: javascript, html

The project on which I am working, is to open the pop up form directly into page. See below:

When you will click on first button a pop up will open:

[image]

And there will need again to click on register button to open the webinar registration form:

[image: Image# 2]

Here is that form:

[image: Image# 3]

I want to open this form on first pop up instead of register button. I got this integration code form EverWebinar:

```html
<link href="//events.genndi.com/assets/css/register_button.css" rel="stylesheet"><div style="margin:auto;width:300px;"><div class="embedded-joinwebinar-button"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default css3button" title="regpopbox_818182175026324685_7b22b2195f"><span>Register now</span></button></div></div><script src="//events.genndi.com/register.evergreen.extra.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" async></script><img src="//events.genndi.com/tracker?action=registration-evergreen&webicode=7b22b2195f&version=&memberid=818182175026324685" style="visibility:hidden; height:0px; width:0px; border:none;">
```

I want to open the webinar form directly on first pop up instead of register button there. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: I want to add the form into first pop up instead of register button there, so customer will just need to click on first button and a pop up will appear with form there. You can check all situation here: https://www.all-in.marketing/spezial-webinar

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to find all kinds of method provided by everwebinar but got nothing there instead of that code. Want this kind of solution https://www.emeacademy.com/webinar when you click on register to open pop up there with form.